# Allowing duplicate value in ui-select component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ui-select` does not allow **duplicated** values to be insert in a select list item. I have one use case where a user can enter a value multiple times. The value entered by the user will not be selected from the drop list.

Is it possible to achieve this with a `ui-select` directive?

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter:$select.search track by $index">
  {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is the sample plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/s407ooeoeFh2dH9DynZy?p=preview

The user may enter manual values like 'a' in this ui select. After entering 'a' once, a user may not enter 'a' again, as ng-repeat do not allowed duplicate value.  I tried to use track by $index so that it can take the array position but I am not able to enter same value twice.

Answer (score 1):

ui-select doesn't currently support this functionality. I [requested this feature](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1855) yesterday and it was unfortunately rejected. I've implemented it in my own fork ([see commit](https://github.com/chrisparton1991/ui-select/commit/154d308a119dbe76d551c31639c3ada005c28966)) and linked that to the issue.

If you still need this feature, you can try forking/downloading my repo, switching to the `feat-duplicates-allowed` branch and building the code with gulp. To enable, simply add `duplicates-allowed="true"` to your `ui-select` element.

Feel free to add a thumbs up or comment to the UI select issue if you think it'd be a useful contribution to the library.

Disclaimer: I've unit tested the basic cases for the feature, and it works for my use case, but I haven't done extensive testing of edge cases.